# Case-sensitive database collation, but case-insensitive SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm running a project with SSIS and now creating new database with CS (case sensitive) collation, but all queries, stored procedures etc. were written in case-insensitive manner, so now SQL Server doesn't recognize them. I need to change table names, columns names... in queries in exact the same as they are in SQL Server.

Is it possible to have CS database with CI stored procedures, queries and so on... ?

Comment: Why not fix the database collation...?

Comment: I need CS on some columns, if all columns would be CS that be the best sollution

Comment: Add CS only where needed to the column. If all columns are CS then *fix your queries* because you can't mix CI and CS conveniently

Comment: In regards to the bounty made by @Impaler : No, there is no option for having different collation settings for system objects and user objects. Object names (like a table's) are stored in in the `sys` objects as a `sysname`, which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`. These columns inherit the default collation of the database, and if you change that collation, then they are changed too ([documentation](//learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation)). As such any change affects **all** the columns; user and system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, case sensitivity at the database level applies to object names. You can, however, create a case insensitive database, and for each text column you create, modify the collation to a case sensitive one. I believe that that would give you the behaviour you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply collation at the column-level. To do this, right click your table in SQL Server Management Studio, click 'Design' then select the column and in the Column Properties menu under the 'Table Designer' section you can choose to use something other than the database default.

Note, it will not let you change the collation on a column if its part of the primary key.

Comment: I would consider this is the most convenient use solution for our use case. After 10 years,  SQL Server's design still doesn't distinguish between case sensitivity for database objects and for VARCHAR columns. The explicit collation is a pain in the neck, but works as expected.